# Merge multiple CSV files in single file and add column name of each csv in first column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Hello everyone i am trying this piece of code but i didn't get my desired output,please help me for getting proper result .

```
import os
import glob   
import pandas as pd


path = r'filespath'

all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))

names = [os.path.basename(x) for x in glob.glob(path+'\*.csv')]

df = pd.DataFrame()

for file_ in all_files:
    file_df = pd.read_csv(file_,sep=';', parse_dates=[0], infer_datetime_format=True,header=None )
    file_df['file_name'] = file_
    df = df.append(file_df)
    print(df)
```

I want to add multiple CSV files in one csv file and add csv file name in first column , if anyone  have idea please share .thanks

Comment: looking forward for solution ,please if anyone can help

Comment: Hi waquar ali, welcome to SO. It will be great if you can produce a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot fully understand the problem you encounter unless you provide the structure of the csvs you use and the result you get.

Can you provide a small example of csv files and the unwanted result so we could understand what the problem is?

To provide a small example, you could use `df.head(2)` on two sample csv files.

## Update

## Suggested Solution

Here is a working example, provided by the example given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21232849/6126315)

The sample i used is:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.asarray([[1, 1], [2, 2]]), columns=['A', 'B'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.asarray([[3, 3], [4, 4]]), columns=['A', 'B'])
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.asarray([[5, 5], [6, 6]]), columns=['A', 'B'])
df1.to_csv('1.csv')
df2.to_csv('2.csv')
df3.to_csv('3.csv')
```

The resulting csvs:

```
   A  B
0  1  1
1  2  2

   A  B
0  3  3
1  4  4

   A  B
0  5  5
1  6  6
```

The concatenation code:

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd

path = r'.'
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))
names = [os.path.basename(x) for x in glob.glob(path+'\*.csv')]
df = pd.DataFrame()

for file_ in all_files:
    file_df = pd.read_csv(file_, index_col=0, header=0)
    file_df['file_name'] = file_
    df = df.append(file_df)
print(df)
```

The concatenation result:

```
   A  B file_name
0  5  5   ./3.csv
1  6  6   ./3.csv
0  1  1   ./1.csv
1  2  2   ./1.csv
0  3  3   ./2.csv
1  4  4   ./2.csv
```

**Notice** that there are two differences from your code:

1. The header parameter is set to *0* instead of *None*.
2. The index_col parameter is set to *0* instead of 'None'.

## Explanation

I guess the problems you encountered are related to these parameters so i will explain their usage.

Say you have the following csv file:

```
,A,B
0,1,1
1,2,2
```

Notice that the first row is the header, and the first row is the index.

When one uses `pandas.read_csv(...)` function, than they will get the following result:

```
   Unnamed: 0  A  B
0           0  1  1
1           1  2  2
```

This means that pandas took the first column, which is the index column, and treated it as a regular data column.
To avoid this, one can to set the *index_col* parameter to 0.
This way pandas will know to parse this column as index.
So the result of `pandas.read_csv(..., index_col=0)` will result in the following:

```
   A  B
0  1  1
1  2  2
```

Now if one reads a few csv files using this method, their concatenation will result in the wanted appearance which does not include their former index, as was shown in the example i provided.

Additionally, if i would've set the *header* parameter to be None, than the entire first row would be considered to be data, and we would've received the following unwanted result:

```
     0  1  2
0  NaN  A  B
1  0.0  1  1
2  1.0  2  2
```

This would lead to an unwanted result in the concatenated dataframe as well.

## Update 2

(The op has mentioned that the new column contains the path of the csv files instead of the basename of the files)

The reason for this problem is because in the line `file_df['file_name'] = file_`.
you used *file_* which iterates over *all_files*.
And indeed *all_files* contains **the path** to your csv files.
You kept the **base names** of your files in the *names* variable, so in order to get the only the base names of the csv files in the new column i suggest the following changes to the code presented above:

```
path = r'.'
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))
names = [os.path.basename(x) for x in all_files]
df = pd.DataFrame()

for file_, name in zip(all_files, names):
    file_df = pd.read_csv(file_, index_col=0)
    file_df['file_name'] = name
    df = df.append(file_df)
print(df)
```

The changes i made are:

1. Corrected the parsing of the base names `names = [os.path.basename(x) for x in all_files]`
2. Used the base names in the new column `file_df['file_name'] = name`

Comment: for your CSV file what results did you get ,please can you send screenshot?

Comment: Hi @Gal given that you updated the answer you should state so. Using an **UPDATE** before the added text.

Comment: Thank you for detail ,its very helpful but still have one more problem. in filename column i get very strange results ,i get in filename columns my direction path,but i require only csv file name in file name column

Comment: @waqarali I see :) i've added the solution to this problem in the answer :)

Comment: @Gal Avineri  Thanks , you make my life easy :) your solution works

Comment: I'm glad i could've helped you! :D

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you to create a function for read and append the filename then you can loop through `all_files`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import glob

path = 'folder'
if not os.path.exists(path):
    os.makedirs(path)


def fun(fn):
    df = pd.read_csv(fn)
    # edit so file_name is the first col
    cols = df.columns.tolist()
    cols = ["file_name"] + cols
    # end edit
    df["file_name"] = fn
    return df[cols]

N = 100
for i in range(10):
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(i*N, (i+1)*N))
    df.to_csv("{}/file_{:02}.csv".format(path, i), index=False)

all_files = sorted(glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv")))

dfs = [fun(fn) for fn in all_files]
df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
df.to_csv("single_file.csv", index=False)
```